# Is it possible to scrape data from public Facebook groups without using the Facebook API?

Tags: python, facebook, graphql

Facebook deprecated the feature to fetch the member list of a Public group from their API back in 2018. Although, there are several "online web based scrapers" that are in fact able to fetch such lists.

Some of these sites use cookies to achieve this, specifically the ***c_user*** and the ***xs*** cookie values. So I assume they are making requests directly to [facebook's graphql API](https://www.facebook.com/api/graphql/).

*I tried to recreate this to see if this actually works, for educational purposes of course*,

Here is the code

```
import requests

C_USER = '{my c_user cookie value}'
XS =  '{my xs cookie value}'



def fetchUsers(gid):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        link = 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/{}/members'.format(gid)
        s.headers['referer'] = 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/{}/members'.format(gid)
        s.headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0; Pixel 2 Build/OPD3.170816.012) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Mobile Safari/537.36'
        s.headers['x-fb-friendly-name'] = 'GroupsCometMembersPageNewForumMembersSectionRefetchQuery'
        s.headers['authority'] = 'www.facebook.com'
        s.headers['content-type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        s.headers['cookie'] = 'datr=KVgYYIAX5zb_krhCp; sb=clgYYE_FY0H6lWP3SnZ; c_user={C_USER}; spin=r.1004833058_b.trunk_t.1639053628_s.1_v.2_; usida=eyJ2ZXIIjoxNjM5MDgzODA3fQ==; x-referer=eyJyIjoiL2Jyb3dzMjg1NjQmc3RhcnQ9MCZsaXN0VHlwZT1saXN0X25vbmZyaWVuZF9ub25hZG1pbiIsImgiOiIvYnJvd3NlL2dyb3VwL21lbWJI1OTE2NzMxOTMyODU2NCZzdGFydD0wJmxpc3RUeXBlPWxpc3Rfbm9uZnJpZW5kX25vbmFkbWluIiwicyI6Im0ifQ==; presence=C{"t3":[{"i":"u.100033204257783"}],"utc3":1639086440727,"v":1}; xs={XS}; fr=0pIsrVrEIGibHFXTR.AWWZGxit3m9NCbQGzc.Bhsnl6.8c.AAA.0.0.Bhsnl6.AWnnLrY; m_pixel_ratio=1; wd=2543x937; dpr=1'
        res = s.post(link)
        
        return res.text
    
print(fetchUsers('{group id}'))
```

Although this returned some weird *HTML code with some JavaScript scripts embedded to it* while I was expecting some *JSON* in the format of the [preview tab from a similar request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRKTB.jpg) made from the actual Facebook site.

Question is, is it the fact that my request is not crafted correctly or that the sites I mentioned above don't use this method to receive the member list of public Facebook groups? If so how do they do it "legally" without violating Facebook's TOS?